# JavaScript: Find & replace a part of URL without refresh, HTML5 history.replacestate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, history.js

I have an URL like this:

```
http://site.com/images/961b7d0e50f0462a8828d31bf0874a71/lightbox
```

I need to `string.format` replace the GUID in the URL with another GUID from the Array (next or previous) without refresh on click event.

HTML:

```
<a id="replaceGUIDnext">Replace GUID to previous in Array</a>
<a id="replaceGUIDprevious">Replace GUID to previous in Array</a>
```

SCRIPT:

```
var guids = ['3ffffb5fb7424c3d96f361fc18a753e0', '961b7d0e50f0462c8828c31bf0874a71', '62a96a75f4764c9ea3d9b65a47dce53d'];
var baseURL = http://site.com/images/{1}/lightbox

$('#replaceGUIDnext').click(function(){
     ...something goes here
});

$('#replaceGUIDprevious').click(function(){
     ...something goes here
});
```

Notice {1} which should be replaced with string.format.

I'd like to use HTML5 `history.replacestate`. If the browser doesn't support it, it should ignore the replace (or fail-back to a working solution).

Comment: OK, have you looked up `replaceState` on MDN? - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript does not have string.format so just use replace.

```
function changeIt( guid ) {
    if( history.replaceState ) {
        var newUrl = baseURL.replace("{1}", guid);
        history.replaceState( { "guid" : guid}, guid, newUrl );
    }
}
```